# '_' is not convertible to 'String'

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, swift2

I'm trying to create a dictionary of attributes to pass into `NSString.drawInRect`. However, Swift won't let me, as the following code results in mysterious error message `'_' is not convertible to 'String'`

```
let font = NSFontManager.sharedFontManager().fontWithFamily(...)
let color = NSColor.whiteColor() 
let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle()
let attributes = [
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
    NSFontAttributeName: font,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color]
```

What needs to be done differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This answer add nothing new to matt's answer so if you upvote this, remember to upvote his as well)

`font` is optional, you can unwrap it with `font!`, like this:

```
let font = NSFontManager.sharedFontManager().fontWithFamily(...)
let color = NSColor.whiteColor() 
let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle()
let attributes = [
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
    NSFontAttributeName: font!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color]
```

Comment: Matt refused to have a example in his answer, so this will be the accepted answer, as it meets the SO standard for proper answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`font` is an Optional. Unwrap it to get the font that's wrapped inside it.

Comment: If you don't agree with the example I edited in, provide a alternative.